# If using unicorn, delayed_jobs and cron jobs, is it safe to set pool to 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails application that is used in 3 different environments. Te serve web requests I'm using unicorn, for background jobs I'm using delayed jobs and for regular tasks I'm using cron jobs that run rake tasks. Is it safe to set pool to 1?

Nowhere in my application I'm creating new threads.

Unicorn is multi-process, not multi-threaded, and I'm creating a new connection per process by using:

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
    Rails.logger.info("Disconnected from ActiveRecord")
  end

  sleep 1
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    Rails.logger.info("Connected to ActiveRecord")
  end
end
```

As far as I know, delayed jobs performs one job at a time and even though I have several workers, each worker is a separate process with its own connection.

The last thing I do is run rake tasks for some maintenance tasks. These are also single processes with a single thread that only need one connection to the database.

Under all of these conditions, is it safe to just have pool: 1 in my database.yml so that not even by accident I may end up with too many connections to PostgreSQL?